# Trigger function on create user in supabase

Tags: postgresql, function, triggers, supabase

Someone has an idea why this function doesn't work. Idea is simple - if it is first user add role array to raw_app_meta_data with admin role else add array with user role. Array because I palnning to have more than one role.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION fn_set_initial_auth_user_role()
RETURNS trigger AS $body$
DECLARE
    user_count int;
BEGIN
    SELECT INTO user_count COUNT(*) FROM auth.users;
    IF user_count=0 THEN
        NEW.raw_app_meta_data = NEW.raw_app_meta_data || json_build_object('role', json_build_array('admin'))::jsonb;
    ELSE
        NEW.raw_app_meta_data = NEW.raw_app_meta_data || json_build_object('role',  json_build_array('user'))::jsonb;
    END IF;
    RETURN NEW;
END;
$body$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER trg_set_initial_auth_user_role
BEFORE INSERT
ON auth.users
FOR EACH ROW
EXECUTE PROCEDURE fn_set_initial_auth_user_role();
```

Expecto set the roles array when user is created.

Comment: Define *..function doesn't work.* Add a more detailed description to your question of what you expected and what you got for a given set of input data.

Comment: When NEW.raw_app_meta_data is null, you can concatenate whatever to this NULL but the result will be NULL. Use CONCAT() or first check for a NULL. `SELECT NULL || 'content';`

Comment: I trying to solve it this way NEW.raw_app_meta_data = COALESCE(NEW.raw_app_meta_data, '{}'::jsonb) || jsonb_build_object('role', jsonb_build_array('admin')); Even  RAISE LOG 'New raw_app_meta_data: %', NEW.raw_app_meta_data; shows proper results -> New raw_app_meta_data: {"role": ["admin"], "provider": "azure", "providers": ["azure"]}. But at the end of transaction, I still see only "{"provider": "azure", "providers": ["azure"]}" with no role. May be it is some supabase not postgress related issue ?